# Problem with CGI.pm - Can't use 'defined(@array)'

Tags: perl, cgi.pm

We have a Perl app that is getting the following error when we try to run it:

```
[root@simfed01 Tier7]# ./smallT.pl
Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at /usr/share/perl5/CGI.pm line 528, <DATA> line 558.
Compilation failed in require at ./smallT.pl line 8, <DATA> line 558.
```

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./smallT.pl line 8,  line 558.

It is kind of puzzling because I was able to literally cut the code down to the couple of "Use" statements:

```
#!/bin/perl


use lib '/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/'; #Needed?
use Net::LDAP;
use Data::Dumper;
use CGI;
use MIME::Base64;
use warnings;
```

and it is still giving he same error

This is the perl version info:

```
[root@simfed01 Tier7]# perl -v

This is perl 5, version 26, subversion 3 (v5.26.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 58 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)
```

and this is being run on a Redhat machine with RHEL 8:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.9 (Ootpa)
```

Has anyone run across this problem and also how to resolve it?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT 1: Version of CGI:

```
[root@simfed01 perl5]# perldoc -m CGI | grep VERSION
$CGI::VERSION='3.51';
  if (exists $ENV{MOD_PERL_API_VERSION} && $ENV{MOD_PERL_API_VERSION} == 2) {
    return $VERSION;
    $CGI::VERSION;
OLD VERSION
NEW VERSION
```

EDIT 2:  The following is the code from CGI.pm on this system - it is the old version of the code that pilcrow cited.

```
    524
525     # if we get called more than once, we want to initialize
526     # ourselves from the original query (which may be gone
527     # if it was read from STDIN originally.)
528     if (defined(@QUERY_PARAM) && !defined($initializer)) {
529         for my $name (@QUERY_PARAM) {
530             my $val = $QUERY_PARAM{$name}; # always an arrayref;
531             $self->param('-name'=>$name,'-value'=> $val);
532             if (defined $val and ref $val eq 'ARRAY') {
533                 for my $fh (grep {defined(fileno($_))} @$val) {
534                    seek($fh,0,0); # reset the filehandle.
```

EDIT 3:  Based on the link that pilcrow mentioned to the commit, I decided to modify the CGI.pm, so that I could at least test if that fixed the problem, and it DID!!  The app is now working after that fix.  I know that this is not a good idea, so I am going to run what I did to our team and see what they want to do.

Comment: What version of CGI.pm, and from what distribution (if applicable)? This error, or a darned similar one, was [fixed twelve years](https://github.com/leejo/CGI.pm/commit/faf06265131acac542fd55abb0c27a587107da1d) ago in CGI 3.61 I believe. Could your 5.8.8 libs be hiding an old, old module?

Comment: pilcrow - I (think I) added the version info for the CGI.pm

Comment: pilcrow - added the CGI.pm code snippet from this system - it is definitely the old code.  What to do?  Can I just edit the CGI.pm code in-place and that would fix it?

Comment: Update the module to the latest version you can tolerate.

Comment: brian - how do I do that (upgrade the module)?

Comment: pilcrow - if you mark what you said above referring to the commit link as an answer, I will accept that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in the CGI that has already been fixed. Upgrade the module.